# Queue name from poison message - MQ / JMS

Tags: queue, jms, ibm-mq, backout

I'm developing a solution to retrieve poison messages from a backout queue in Websphere 6.1.

My question is: when this msg (ie. TextMessage) is re-queue from a regular queue to backout queue, what is the queue name in msg.getJMSDestination() and msg.getJMSReplyTo()?

For example:
I've got a msg with destination to myQueue. However, for some reason, this msg could not be processed (poison message) and, because websphere is configured for that, this msg is re-queued to backout queue named myBOQueue. If I retrieve this msg from myBOQueue (using MDB), and I execute  **((Queue) msg.getJMSDestination()).getQueueName()**, what do i go: myQueue or myBOQueue? And if I execute **((Queue) msg.getJMSReplyTo()).getQueueName()**, what do I got?

Message document: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html

Thx,
Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look in vendor-specific docs. I think retry counts and poison message queues are a vendor-specific feature not included in the JMS spec.

Comment: I was able to simulate and check the the queue name in Poison Message JMS Header in getJMSDestination() is the original queue, not the backout queue. However I don't know if it's vendor-specific or JMS default.

Comment: My point was that the bigger feature (retries, poison queue) is a vendor extension.  So you couldn't standardize a small detail, value of getJMSDestination, if the bigger feature isn't standardized.  In other words, the question of what you'll get from getJMSDestination when the message is redirected to a poison queue isn't standardizable because the concept of redirecting to a poison queue isn't in the standard.